# Retrieve numbered data by php for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I create below php for loop for retrieve five numbered images. in this case only show me the `$i` value from 1 to 4 and don't print the `$img_link` and `$img_path` value

**For example:** in image 1 `<a href="'.$img_path.$i'">` print `<a href="1">` means only show `$i` value and don't show full url value

**For Information** When i put `$img_link1` show me the full url without any proplem.

how i can use this code to print `$img_link1, $img_path1` to `$img_link4, $img_path4`?

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<5 ; $i++) {
    echo 
        '<li>
            <figure>
                <a href="'.$img_path.$i'">
                    <img src="'.$img_link1.$i'" />
                </a>
            </figure>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: can you restructure your question or add data, sorta confused exactly what you're trying to do .

Comment: also, it's very dependent on $img_path and $img_link1, where you're defining them, what you're setting them to be, etc. Provide examples of that and we can take a better look at your problem.

Comment: my question it is explained perfectly

Comment: @ Logan Bentley i say how i can get $img_link1 to $img_link4 by using for loop? because i don't want repeat the code four times.

Comment: @SAFEEN1990 I am sorry, but I do not believe I can help you without more information, or better explained.

Comment: You may want to do a Foreach statement. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php then do a IF statement and loop from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these variable variable using :

```
${'img_path'.$i}
```

So your code will look like :

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<5 ; $i++) {
    echo 
        '<li>
            <figure>
                <a href="'.${'img_path'.$i}'">
                    <img src="'.${'img_link'.$i}'" />
                </a>
            </figure>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

You can take a look at the documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
// try this
<img src="'. $img_link$i .'" />
```